# String to binary in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to convert a string to bytes in python 2.7 using the bytes function, and it seems that my bytes function is a pointer to str.

When using str.encode() it just returns a the same string.

Sounds familiar to someone?

Comment: Your string is *already* bytes. Python 2 `str` is a bytestring type, not Unicode.

Comment: [CPython 2.7 reached end-of-life at the end of 2019](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). Unless you have a very good reason, I suggest you move to a recent Python 3 (3.11 is current).

Answer (score -1):

In Python 2.7, the bytes function is not available and the str type is used to represent both text and binary data.

The below code will generate string to byte using utf8 encoding.

```
string = "hello"
bytes = string.encode('utf-8')
```

In Python 2.7, when you print a bytes object, it will be displayed with the b prefix.

Output:

```
b'hello'
```